# I want to insert a slicer in a sheet ,but data is in another sheet

Tags: excel

Slicers are inserted in same sheet as the data, but i want to insert slicer in another sheet. So
how to insert a slicer in a sheet, when  data is in anothet sheet.

Comment: Please provide some more background. Are you working with several sheets that you are loading into pivot? Have you tried connecting them via a unique key? Why are they in different sheets - could you copy them into one?

Comment: i am selecting a company name using slicer and pivot table stores the value of the slicer in a cell.

Comment: Could you add some example data? I am still not sure why you cannot link the two tables prior to what you are doing or whether linking them in pivot would work. Please make sure to always share an example that helps us reproduce / understand the problem and describe what you have tried so far.